# SQL código não funciona queria uma explicação do porque do erro no código?

Tags: sql

[image: Tabelas SQL]

Recebi essas duas tabelas num exercício, porém meu código não tá funcionando e eu queria saber se alguém poderia me explicar. eu tenho que apresentar todas as ordens criadas nos últimos 10 dias.

Meu código:

```
Select id-order, createdDate
From Date
Where Date = 'createDate' in <10 days
```

Só que não funciona.

Comment: Qual o `SGBD`? `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, `Oracle`?

Comment: SQL server.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo visto o que precisa fazer é algo assim:

```
SELECT 
    ID-ORDER, CREATEDDATE
FROM
    ORDER
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(DAY,CREATEDDATE,GETDATE()) < 10
```

Comment: Então preciso usar DateDiff em todos os casos assim?

Comment: Na maioria dos casos, que faz comparação de período entre datas acredito que seja a melhor opção.